# Trying to programmically generate unused receiving address from a xPub

Tags: address, address-generation, xpub

I'm trying to generate unused receiving Bitcoin address from xPub using [PyWallet](https://github.com/ranaroussi/pywallet) python library .
I got the xPub from my BIP32 Electrum wallet.

Here is what I tried

```
from pywallet import wallet

WALLET_PUBKEY = 'xpub....'

# Generate a random address, based on timestamp
rand_addr = wallet.create_address(network="BTC", xpub=WALLET_PUBKEY)

print("Random Address\n", rand_addr)
```

I sent a few cents worth of Bitcoin to it's printed address but I didn't receive it.
What is wrong here and what is the solution ?

Comment: For starters, you should test this on testnet instead of with actual BTC.

Comment: @PieterWuille How to do that?

Comment: @PieterWuille Ok. I just figured out how to use testnet wallet but I don’t know how to use testnet network with PyWallet